# Flutter- masking effect like Wizard school App

Tags: dart, flutter

Here I want to make a masking effect, like Wizard School app.
Here I am using `RenderProxyBox` but I can do only one mask at one time, I want to give multi-time effect. Using `blendMode.clear` here I am removing the cover image, and revealing reveals the image. So, is there any other way to implement multi masking effect as given in Expected section.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/rendering.dart';
import 'dart: math' as math;
class DemoApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Scratch Card',
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text('Scratch Card'),
        ),
        body: Material(
          child: Center(
            child: SizedBox(
              width: 500.0,
              height: 500.0,
              child: Stack(
                children: <Widget>[
                  ScratchCard(
                    cover: Stack(
                      fit: StackFit.expand,
                      children: <Widget>[
                        FittedBox(
                          child: Image.asset(
                            'assets/bird.jpg',
                            repeat: ImageRepeat.repeat,
                          ),
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                    reveal: DecoratedBox(
                      decoration: const BoxDecoration(color: Colors.black),
                      child: Center(
                        child:
                            FittedBox(child: Image.asset('assets/flower.jpg')),
                      ),
                    ),
                    strokeWidth: 15.0,
                    finishPercent: 50,
                    onComplete: () => print('The card is now clear!'),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class ScratchCard extends StatefulWidget {
  const ScratchCard({
    Key key,
    this.cover,
    this.reveal,
    this.strokeWidth = 25.0,
    this.finishPercent,
    this.onComplete,
  }) : super(key: key);

  final Widget cover;
  final Widget reveal;
  final double strokeWidth;
  final int finishPercent;
  final VoidCallback onComplete;

  @override
  _ScratchCardState createState() => _ScratchCardState();
}

class _ScratchCardState extends State<ScratchCard> {
  _ScratchData _data = _ScratchData();

  Offset _lastPoint = null;

  Offset _globalToLocal(Offset global) {
    return (context.findRenderObject() as RenderBox).globalToLocal(global);
  }

  double _distanceBetween(Offset point1, Offset point2) {
    return math.sqrt(math.pow(point2.dx - point1.dx, 2) +
        math.pow(point2.dy - point1.dy, 2));
  }

  double _angleBetween(Offset point1, Offset point2) {
    return math.atan2(point2.dx - point1.dx, point2.dy - point1.dy);
  }

  void _onPanDown(DragDownDetails details) {
    _lastPoint = _globalToLocal(details.globalPosition);
  }

  void _onPanUpdate(DragUpdateDetails details) {
    final currentPoint = _globalToLocal(details.globalPosition);
    final distance = _distanceBetween(_lastPoint, currentPoint);
    final angle = _angleBetween(_lastPoint, currentPoint);
    for (double i = 0.0; i < distance; i++) {
      _data.addPoint(Offset(
        _lastPoint.dx + (math.sin(angle) * i),
        _lastPoint.dy + (math.cos(angle) * i),
      ));
    }
    _lastPoint = currentPoint;
  }

  void _onPanEnd(TapUpDetails details) {
    final areaRect = context.size.width * context.size.height;
    double touchArea = math.pi * widget.strokeWidth * widget.strokeWidth;
    double areaRevealed =
        _data._points.fold(0.0, (double prev, Offset point) => touchArea);
    print('areaRect $areaRect $areaRevealed');
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return GestureDetector(
      behavior: HitTestBehavior.opaque,
      onPanDown: _onPanDown,
      onPanUpdate: _onPanUpdate,
      onTapUp: _onPanEnd,
      child: Stack(
        fit: StackFit.expand,
        children: <Widget>[
          widget.reveal,
          _ScratchCardLayout(
            strokeWidth: widget.strokeWidth,
            data: _data,
            child: widget.cover,
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}

class _ScratchCardLayout extends SingleChildRenderObjectWidget {
  _ScratchCardLayout({
    Key key,
    this.strokeWidth = 25.0,
    @required this.data,
    @required this.child,
  }) : super(
          key: key,
          child: child,
        );

  final Widget child;
  final double strokeWidth;
  final _ScratchData data;

  @override
  RenderObject createRenderObject(BuildContext context) {
    return _ScratchCardRender(
      strokeWidth: strokeWidth,
      data: data,
    );
  }

  @override
  void updateRenderObject(
      BuildContext context, _ScratchCardRender renderObject) {
    renderObject
      ..strokeWidth = strokeWidth
      ..data = data;
  }
}

class _ScratchCardRender extends RenderProxyBox {
  _ScratchCardRender({
    RenderBox child,
    double strokeWidth,
    _ScratchData data,
  })  : assert(data != null),
        _strokeWidth = strokeWidth,
        _data = data,
        super(child);

  double _strokeWidth;
  _ScratchData _data;

  set strokeWidth(double strokeWidth) {
    assert(strokeWidth != null);
    if (_strokeWidth == strokeWidth) {
      return;
    }
    _strokeWidth = strokeWidth;
    markNeedsPaint();
  }

  set data(_ScratchData data) {
    assert(data != null);
    if (_data == data) {
      return;
    }
    if (attached) {
      _data.removeListener(markNeedsPaint);
      data.addListener(markNeedsPaint);
    }
    _data = data;
    markNeedsPaint();
  }

  @override
  void attach(PipelineOwner owner) {
    super.attach(owner);
    _data.addListener(markNeedsPaint);
  }

  @override
  void detach() {
    _data.removeListener(markNeedsPaint);
    super.detach();
  }

  @override
  void paint(PaintingContext context, Offset offset) {
    if (child != null) {
      context.canvas.saveLayer(offset & size, Paint());
      context.paintChild(child, offset);
      Paint clear = Paint()..blendMode = BlendMode.clear;
      _data._points.forEach((point) =>
          context.canvas.drawCircle(offset + point, _strokeWidth, clear));
      context.canvas.restore();
    }
  }

  @override
  bool get alwaysNeedsCompositing => child != null;
}

class _ScratchData extends ChangeNotifier {
  List<Offset> _points = [];

  void addPoint(Offset offset) {
    _points.add(offset);
    notifyListeners();
  }
}
```

output:- [image]

Expected: - [image: This first-time image masking is selected]
If I change the color/image than- [image]
I want to change the color/image with the new one and keep previous one.

Comment: Problem solved, Using ``ImageShader``

Comment: I think the rest of the thing you have to complete, as you can see, the first step, 2nd, and 3rd. So you have to very well knowledge were to put these code. Still, if you are not able to do, then I will send you a GitHub link.

Comment: Ok, I will very soon, right now I am a little busy.

Comment: Hey, this is my git link here I have created one paint app. in which you can paint, erase and masking as well. https://github.com/satishsoni777/masking

Answer (score 1):

Step 1 convert JPG/PNG to `ui.Image` format using this code.

```
ui.Image uiImage;
  static Future<void> cacheImage(String asset) async {
        if (maskImageMap[asset] == null) {
          try {
            ByteData data = await rootBundle.load(asset);
            ui.Codec codec = await ui.instantiateImageCodec(
              data.buffer.asUint8List(),
            );
            ui.FrameInfo fi = await codec.getNextFrame();
           uiImage = fi.image;
          } catch (e) {
            print(e);
          }
        }
      }
```

Step 2: Divide the image in the pixel format.

```
final Float64List deviceTransform = new Float64List(16)
      ..[0] = devicePixelRatio
      ..[5] = devicePixelRatio
      ..[10] = 1.0
      ..[15] = 3.5;
```

Step 3:  Use ImageShader to give mask filter effect.

```
 canvas.saveLayer();
        Paint().shader = ImageShader(uiImage,
                  TileMode.repeated, TileMode.repeated, deviceTransform);
```

If this answer is not enough then here is my git link
[A Paint Application](https://github.com/satishsoni777/masking)